# Convert polygon to ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, polygon, ellipse

**Background:**

I have a set of point which I run through a convex hull algorithm, these points returned are then drawn as a polygon on the screen.

**Aim:**

I want to "smooth" out the polygon into an ellipse/oval like shape.

Is there a simple way to do this or is there an algorithm for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I can't seem to find any way of doing this.

Comment: Very primitive, but as long as the ellipse is oriented along the x- and y-axis, you may simply create it from the [Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.bounds.aspx) of the polyline geometry.

Comment: Yeah that's actually a good idea however, because I am drawing the polygon from a set of points the bounds of it are not set correctly, they are always 0,0. I think I have an idea though... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got something that works...

Because I am drawing a polygon from a set of points, the width/height/bounds are not set correctly (always 0, not sure if its my fault or not?), however, I do have the points that make up the polygon.

What I decided to do was loop through the points getting the left most x, right most x, top most y and bottom most y. This then allows me to work out the width, height and position to draw the ellipse at.

The result is this:
[image]

Thanks to Clemens for the help :)

If there is a better way of doing this please let me know.